# C# vs Java - Generic Lists

Tags: c#, java, list

What are the differences of the C# and Java implementations of the generic List class?

Comment: Well, for one, List (http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is an interface in Java, not a class.  Java's equivalent to the C# generic List class is ArrayList<T>

Comment: although a bit dated, seems interesting: http://www.artima.com/intv/generics.html

Answer (score 33):

Well, in Java `List<T>` is an interface, to start with :)

The most important difference between the two is the difference between C# and Java generics to start with: in Java generics basically perform compile-time checks and include some metadata in generic fields etc - but the actual *object* doesn't know its generic type at execution time. You can't ask a `List<?>` what that ? is, in other words. Any references to a generic type parameter in the implementation act as `Object`, basically - so a `ArayList<String>` is really backed by an `Object[]`. In C# all the information is available at execution time too - so a `List<string>` is backed by a `string[]`.

Similarly C# generics allow value type type arguments, so you can have a `List<int>` in C# but not in Java.

There are further differences in terms of variance etc - but this is moving a long way from `List<T>`.

In terms of *just* `ArrayList<T>` (Java) and `List<T>` (.NET), a couple of differences:

- Java lists override equals/hashCode, whereas they don't in .NET
- `ArrayList<T>` grows by multiplying the current capacity by 3/2; .NET's `List<T>` doubles the current capacity instead

Of course there are other differences in terms of the APIs exposed - if you could give more information about the kind of difference you're interested in, we could help more.

Comment: And I remember asking why you would always get upvotes @ meta. Great answer.

Comment: But C# List<T> is a list implementation, I'm wondering if I should be using IList<__> everywhere because I should always program to an interface, not an implementation. I'm seeing lots of C# code use specific List as return types which is wrong. If someone decides to use a diff implementation of IList then more than 1 place has to change.

Answer (score 4):

Are you asking for differences in their API or their underlying implementation?  I believe Java generics are implemented completely via the compiler -- the JVM has no notion of generics.  For C#, generics are a built-in concept of the .Net runtime.  Wikipedia seems to have a good comparison of the two: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_C_Sharp_and_Java#Generics