# Java Equivalent of C# ArrayList

Tags: java, c#, arraylist

I'm converting a C# code to a Java code.

ArrayList is used in that C# code.

Should I directly use ArrayList in Java code for C# ArrayList?

When I directly use, I get this warning :

> ArrayList is a raw type. References to generic type ArrayList
>   should be parameterized.

What changes should I do?

My C# Arraylist :

```
private System.Collections.ArrayList _lines = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
        public System.Collections.ArrayList Lines
        {
            get { return lines; }
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add some code.

Comment: Have you [searched](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ArrayList%20is%20a%20raw%20type.%20References%20to%20generic%20type%20ArrayList%20should%20be%20parameterized.)?

Comment: I did, I found Java to C# but not the opposite.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486277/c-sharp-vs-java-generic-lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make more or less 1 to 1 conversion, then you can use `ArrayList<Object>`:

```
ArrayList<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

It will allow you to convert code without major rewrite.

But I'd recommend to use generic version of the appropriate Collections, whether in Java or C# code. Determine the type of lines stored in list and use it as the type parameter of generic collection:

```
ArrayList<Line> arrayList = new ArrayList<Line>();
```

Answer (score 2):

**ArrayList** in **Java** needs to parametrized. You must define a data type. See the line below for declaring `ArrayList`

```
List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

arrayList.add("item1");
...
```

Comment: Not really - the legacy Java non-generic ArrayList is still supported, but the compiler assumes you intended the generic ArrayList, forgetting to specify the type. You can always ignore the warning and continue, but obviously it's better to upgrade to the generic version.

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList` is also available in **Java**.

see the [Javadocs here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and also another tutorial [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arraylist_class.htm)

### Example

```
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayListDemo {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      // create an array list
      ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
      System.out.println("Initial size of al: " + al.size());

      // add elements to the array list
      al.add("C");
      al.add("A");
      al.add("E");
      al.add("B");
      al.add("D");
      al.add("F");
      al.add(1, "A2");
      System.out.println("Size of al after additions: " + al.size());

      // display the array list
      System.out.println("Contents of al: " + al);
      // Remove elements from the array list
      al.remove("F");
      al.remove(2);
      System.out.println("Size of al after deletions: " + al.size());
      System.out.println("Contents of al: " + al);
   }
}
```