# Equivalent in c# of java generic type parameter

Tags: java, c#

I have this method in Java which I would like to implement in C#, but I don't know exactly how.

```
public static <T> Set<T> getAddedItems(Set<T> before, Set<T> after) {
    Set<T> out = new HashSet<T>(after);
    out.removeAll(before);
    return out;
}
```

For implementing `Set<T>`, I have chosen the class `HashSet<T>`. The problem is that I don't know what to do with the generic type parameter `<T>`. I am quite new to C# and in Java I hadn't worked with generics until a couple weeks ago, so my apologies if my question is too obvious.

Comment: what does `<T>` mean after `static`? I think it should be removed in first place.
Maybe you mean `public static T getAddedItems` ? Or `public static Set<T> getAddedItems`

Comment: Did you try Googling "C# generics"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# vs Java - Generic Lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486277/c-sharp-vs-java-generic-lists)

Comment: @dotNET, yes, I pasted Java code.

Comment: I don't know why the downvotes?

Comment: @Biurrun: Because you didn't make any effort to find the answer yourself.

Comment: @SLaks actually I spend a long time trying to figure it out  but I just didn't know how to exactly look for it :/ Anyway, at least now it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
public static HashSet<T> getAddedItems<T>(HashSet<T> before, HashSet<T> after)
{
  HashSet<T> out2 = new HashSet<T>(after);
  out2.RemoveWhere(x => before.Contains(x));
  return out2;
}
```

`out` is a keyword in C#, so i've renamed that slightly. Also note that `HashSet` doesn't have `RemoveAll()`, but `RemoveWhere()` appears to do the same thing (needs linq though).

Comment: I had already noticed the points about out and RemoveAll, but thank you anyway! Your solution seems to work!

Comment: 'Set' in Java is an interface, so the C# equivalent would be the "ISet" interface.

Answer (score 0):

This here is 100% valid java...

```
public static <T> Set<T> getAddedItems(Set<T> before, Set<T> after) {
    Set<T> out = new HashSet<T>(after);
    out.removeAll(before);
    return out;
}
```

so far so good, now in  **C#**
you dont need the T notation in the method like java, just need to return the generic `HashSet<T>`

```
public static HashSet<T> GetQueryString<T>(HashSet<T> before, HashSet<T> after)
{
    HashSet<T> returnHashSet = new HashSet<T>(after);
    returnHashSet.RemoveWhere(x => before.Contains(x));
    return returnHashSet;
}
```